# Join Table to Itself for Last Year Results with Missing Dates

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have a table of dates, channels, and sessions and I am trying to use a join command to add columns for each row containing the relevant value last year, however, I want to include the dates from last year that have no value this year and vice versa. The problem is that for dates that don't exist, I am getting doubling of the rows. Any thoughts on how to fix?

```
SELECT
  ty.*,
  ly.Date as Date_LY,
  ly.Sessions as Sessions_LY
FROM
  `testjoin` AS ty
FULL JOIN
  `testjoin` as ly
  ON
  ly.Date = DATE_SUB(ty.Date, INTERVAl 1 YEAR)
  AND ly.Channel = ty.Channel
```

Data:

```
Date        Channel Sessions
01/01/2017  Email   5
02/02/2017  Email   10
01/01/2018  Email   11
02/02/2018  Email   17
01/01/2017  Organic 10
02/02/2017  Organic 15
01/01/2018  Organic 20
```

Desired Output:

```
Date    Channel Sessions    Sessions_LY
01/01/2017  Email   5   null
02/02/2017  Email   10  null
01/01/2018  Email   11  5
02/02/2018  Email   17  10
01/01/2017  Organic 10  null
02/02/2017  Organic 15  null
01/01/2018  Organic 20  10
02/02/2018  Organic null    15
```

Actual Output:

```
Date        Channel Sessions    Sessions_LY
01/01/2017  Organic 10  
02/02/2017  Email   10  
02/02/2017  Organic 15  
01/01/2017  Email   5   
01/01/2018  Email   11  5
01/01/2018  Organic 20  10
02/02/2018  Email   17  10
                        15
                        11
                        20
                        17
```

Comment: did you have chance to try any of below answers?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, thanks for following up. I have been playing with the answers as the actual data set has numerous years and 16 dimensions so the query complexity was quite high. Still working through getting it to work, but I think I have all the pieces thanks to you guys in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the values:

```
SELECT d.Date, c.Channel, ty.Sessions, ty_prev.Sessions
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ty.Date
      FROM testjoin ty
     ) d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT ty.channel FROM testjoin ty) c LEFT JOIN
     testjoin ty
     ON ty.Date = d.Date AND ty.Channel = c.Channel LEFT JOIN
     testjoin ty_prev
     ON ty_prev.Date = d.date - interval 1 year and ty.Channel = c.Channel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Play with datepart as per your needs

`with t (date, channel, sessions) as
(
select '01/01/2017',  'Email',   5  union all
select '02/02/2017',  'Email',   10 union all
select '01/01/2018',  'Email',   11 union all
select '02/02/2018',  'Email',   17 union all
select '01/01/2017',  'Organic', 10 union all
select '02/02/2017',  'Organic', 15 union all
select '01/01/2018',  'Organic', 20 
)
select *, lag(sessions) over (partition by d.channel, datepart(mm, d.date) order by d.channel, datepart(mm, d.date)) l
  from (select * from ((SELECT DISTINCT t.Date
      FROM t) d
      CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT t.channel FROM t) c)) d left join t on d.Date = t.Date and d.channel = t.channel
     order by d.channel, datepart(yyyy,d.date), datepart(mm, d.date)`

Answer (score 0):

Everything in  your question indicates that you have only current(2018) and previous (2017) so below is based on this assumption and is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', Date) Date, Channel, Sessions
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table` 
), all_days AS ( 
  SELECT Date, Channel FROM temp UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT DATE_ADD(Date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), Channel 
    FROM temp WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) = 2017
), all_data AS (
  SELECT Date, Channel, Sessions, FORMAT_DATE('%m%d', Date) day
  FROM all_days
  LEFT JOIN temp USING(Date, Channel)
)
SELECT Date, Channel, Sessions, 
  LAG(Sessions) OVER(PARTITION BY day, Channel ORDER BY Date) Sessions_LY
FROM all_data
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT '01/01/2017' Date, 'Email' Channel, 5 Sessions UNION ALL
  SELECT '02/02/2017', 'Email', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2018', 'Email', 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT '02/02/2018', 'Email', 17 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2017', 'Organic', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '02/02/2017', 'Organic', 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2018', 'Organic', 20 
), temp AS (
  SELECT PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', Date) Date, Channel, Sessions
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table` 
), all_days AS ( 
  SELECT Date, Channel FROM temp UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT DATE_ADD(Date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), Channel 
    FROM temp WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) = 2017
), all_data AS (
  SELECT Date, Channel, Sessions, FORMAT_DATE('%m%d', Date) day
  FROM all_days
  LEFT JOIN temp USING(Date, Channel)
)
SELECT Date, Channel, Sessions, 
  LAG(Sessions) OVER(PARTITION BY day, Channel ORDER BY Date) Sessions_LY
FROM all_data
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

result is

```sql
Row Date        Channel     Sessions    Sessions_LY  
1   2017-01-01  Email       5           null     
2   2017-02-02  Email       10          null     
3   2018-01-01  Email       11          5    
4   2018-02-02  Email       17          10   
5   2017-01-01  Organic     10          null     
6   2017-02-02  Organic     15          null     
7   2018-01-01  Organic     20          10   
8   2018-02-02  Organic     null        15
```